# Applescript exits return loop before complete

Tags: macos, applescript, bash

I have to go through a stack of hard drives & usb keys looking for old quickbook files.  So, I've written an applescript which triggers when a new drive is mounted.  It then searches the drive for qbb or qbo files and copies them to a folder on the main drive.

I have it working almost perfectly but, for the life of me, I cannot get the repeat loop to run past the first item in the list.  So, it grabs qbb files, but not qbo files.  I know it is failing because I trigger it with a USB kye that has dummy qbo and qbb files on it.

I know I am missing something obvious, but keep racking my brain to no avail.

Here is my script.  Can someone please give me sanity check (and solution)?

Thanks!

```
on adding folder items to thisFolder after receiving addedItems

   # set the path for the files to be copied too.
   set thePath to ((path to home folder as text) & "00_QBB:")
   if not pathExists(thePath) then
       display dialog "Could not find the path. Files have not been copied."
       return
   end if

   try
       # get name of Loaded Drive
       set loadedDriveName to item 1 of addedItems

       # set paths for source source drive
       set loadedDrive to POSIX path of loadedDriveName 

       # create folder, named for Loaded Drive, for inbound copies
       set thePath to thePath & loadedDriveName
       set thePath to POSIX path of thePath
       set makeFolder to "mkdir " & thePath 
       # display dialog makeFolder
       do shell script (makeFolder)

       # set search criteria
       set qbFileTypes to {"qbb", "qbo"}

       # lookthrough drive for desired file types to find and copy
       repeat with n from 1 to (count of qbFiletypes)
           set qbCount to (count of qbFiletypes)
           set qbCurrentType to (item n of qbFiletypes)
           # display dialog qbCurrentType & " + " & qbCount
           set grab_qbb to "find " & loadedDrive & " -iname \"*" & qbCurrentType & "*\" -exec cp {} " & thePath & " \\;"
           # display dialog grab_qbb
           do shell script (grab_qbb)
       end repeat

       on error
           display dialog "Could not copy files."
       return
   end try

end adding folder items to

on pathExists(thePath) -- pathExists("path:to:folder: OR :file")
   try
       get thePath as alias
       return true
       on error
       return false
   end try
end pathExists
```

Comment: [Stack Overflow has a wonderful concept of MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - if no one invests enough time to read every line of your script, perhaps consider reducing it to the bare minimum lines needed to show your error. If you had 5 lines, it might be that many people can spot your error. This borders on something you would pay someone to debug, but it’s OK to post a question, just many people won’t get past the wall of text.

Comment: re: cross-posting: Understood. A friend said this was the best pace for my question. So, I moved it here and forgot to delete the original. Original deleted.

Comment: I've tested your _code_ verbatim and it works. It copied both `.qbb` and `.qbo` _files_. That said, as coded, it has to run the `find` _command_ twice using `do shell script` and this is not at all necessary with a properly formed `find` _command_. Which also eliminates the need for the `repeat with n from 1 to (count of qbFiletypes)` _loop_. As a hint, here is an example if run in **Terminal**: `find "/path/to/source" -type f \( -iname '*.qbb' -o -iname '*.qbo' \) -exec cp -an {} "/path/to/destination" \;`

Comment: I guess I have to take back "I've tested your code verbatim" because **Script Editor** corrected the mismatched _camelCase_ names of the _variable_ pointed out in # 3 of kenjikato's. That said though, I still stand by the rest of my first comment and the answer I posted.

Comment: Come to think of it, `qbFileTypes` and `qbFiletypes` are the same thing as far as **AppleScript** is concerned. The _camelCase_ just makes it easier to read, and as long as the _variable_ has the same number of characters and same letters, regardless of case, **AppleScript** it going to treat `qbFileTypes` and `qbFiletypes` as the same thing. In **Terminal** `osascript -e 'set qbFileTypes to "foobar"' -e 'return qbFiletypes'` returns `foobar` as it should, so # 3 in kenjikato's answer is not a valid point.

Answer (score 1):

I would have gone about this a bit differently.

First, I'd use [Disk Arbitrator](https://github.com/aburgh/Disk-Arbitrator) so the external disks would mount read-only and not preform any **Spotlight** *indexing*. There's no need to allow *indexing* if the target is just `.qbb` and `.qbo` *files* to be found using the `find` *command*.

Second, I'd use an **Automator** *Folder Action* with a **Run Shell Script** *action*, as IMO it's just much easier to *code*.

The following *example* `bash` *code* preforms these tasks:

- Creates all **destination** *directories* as needed.
- Handles disks with multiple volumes.
- Finds the `.qbb` and `.qbo` *files* and copies them.
- Ejects the target disk when finished copying.
- Notifies the *process* has completed.

Also, as an **Automator** *Folder Action* there is a icon on the menu bar which aside from being a visual indicator a process is running, it also allows one to terminate the process if necessary.

Setup the **Automator** *Folder Action* as shown below:

[image: Automator Folder Action]

<sup>Hint: Open image in new tab to clearly see settings.</sup>

---

When the process is finished it displays the following notification and makes a sound, which can be omitted if not wanted.

[image: Notification Image]

---

***Example* `bash` *code*:**

```
p="$HOME/00_QBB"

[ ! -d "${p}" ] && mkdir "${p}"

for d in "$@"; do
    n="$(basename "$d")"
    mkdir -p "${p}/${n}"
    find "$d" -type f \( -iname '*.qbb' -o -iname '*.qbo' \) -exec cp -an {} "${p}/${n}" \; 
done

sleep 3
diskutil eject "$1"

osascript -e 'display notification "Insert another disk to start new search..." with title "QuickBooks File Recovery" subtitle "The find command has completed." sound name "Purr"
```

---

Obviously you might be inserting disks that you do not need to or want to search, so you can use **Folder Action Setup** to enable/disable this easily.

I use **Spotlight** to bring up **Folder Action Setup** and then check/uncheck the checkboxes as necessary.

[image: Folder Action Setup]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make your script work properly with a couple of small changes, and a couple of additions that will make sure things run smoothly .

Most likely your main error is item 3 from these changes.

1. You should not overwrite the `thePath` var on line 19, rather set the `POSIX` output to a new variable like `saveToPath`. This in turn means you need to change `thePath` var on lines 20 and 32 to `saveToPath`.
2. You should add the `-p` option to your `mkdir` command on line 20. So the quoted part on that line should be `"mkdir -p "`. Make sure there is a space after the `-p`.
3. On lines 28, 29 and 30 your `qbFileTypes` var is not using the proper camel case var name as you have a lowercase `t` rather than an uppercase `T` in the original var. Change the vars to all be `qbFileTypes` on those lines.
4. For more verbose error handling I would change your `on error` to the following. This will give you a better idea if something actually goes wrong, and what the error is.

```
on error errStr number errorNumber
     display dialog "Could not copy files becuase " & errStr & " error# " & errorNumber
     return
end try
```

Below is your code with these changes made to it.

I hope this works for you. Cheers!

---

```
on adding folder items to thisFolder after receiving addedItems

    # set the path for the files to be copied too.
    set thePath to ((path to home folder as text) & "goesHere:")
    if not pathExists(thePath) then
        display dialog "Could not find the path. Files have not been copied."
        return
    end if

    try
        # get name of Loaded Drive
        set loadedDriveName to item 1 of addedItems

        # set paths for source source drive
        set loadedDrive to POSIX path of loadedDriveName

        # create folder, named for Loaded Drive, for inbound copies
        set thePath to thePath & loadedDriveName
        set saveToPath to POSIX path of thePath
        set makeFolder to "mkdir -p " & saveToPath
        #display dialog makeFolder
        do shell script (makeFolder)

        # set search criteria
        set qbFileTypes to {"qbb", "qbo"}

        # lookthrough drive for desired file types to find and copy
        repeat with n from 1 to (count of qbFileTypes)
            set qbCount to (count of qbFileTypes)
            set qbCurrentType to (item n of qbFileTypes)
            # display dialog qbCurrentType & " + " & qbCount
            set grab_qbb to "find " & loadedDrive & " -iname \"*" & qbCurrentType & "*\" -exec cp {} " & saveToPath & " \\;"
            # display dialog grab_qbb
            do shell script (grab_qbb)
        end repeat

    on error errStr number errorNumber
        display dialog "Could not copy files becuase " & errStr & " error# " & errorNumber
        return
    end try

end adding folder items to

on pathExists(thePath) -- pathExists("path:to:folder: OR :file")
    try
        get thePath as alias
        return true
    on error
        return false
    end try
end pathExists
```

Comment: Interesting on 3.,  when I copied and pasted the _code_ from the OP to **Script Editor** and saved it so it could be run as a **Folder Action** it corrected the mismatched _camelCase_, so it then ran without issue. It also corrected the mismatched _camelCase_ when hitting the **Compile** button in both **Script Editor** and in **Automator**  with a **Run AppleScript** _action_. It would be interesting to find out in what editor, or what, he wrote the _code_ in that it stayed mismatched.

Comment: Come to think of it, `qbFileTypes` and `qbFiletypes` are the same thing as far as **AppleScript** is concerned. The _camelCase_ just makes it easier to read, and as long as the _variable_ has the same number of characters and same letters, regardless of case, **AppleScript** it going to treat `qbFileTypes` and `qbFiletypes` as the same thing. In **Terminal** `osascript -e 'set qbFileTypes to "foobar"' -e 'return qbFiletypes'` returns `foobar` as it should, so your # 3 is not a valid point.

Comment: I use Coda as my editor.  It does some code highlighting, but I am not sure it specifically does it for AppleScript.  So, perhaps there is something in play there.

Comment: @kenjikato - Tried this and it is still copying only qbb files.

Here is the error I am getting:

`Could not copy files because find: /Volumes/TEST_DRIVE//.Spotlight-V100: Operation not permitted
find: /Volumes/TEST_DRIVE//.Trashes: Operation not permitted error# 1`

Comment: hey @kenjikato - I found the problem. Apparently, applescripts have a known issue with repeating shell calls within loops.  They just fail as this script is.

So, I rewote the script to use the loop to assemble the multiple file requests in a string that is then injected into the shell command and run once.

Works like a charm.

And, your fixes were still key, because they resolved some issues I could not see which, coupled with the better error reporting helped me troubleshoot and zero in on the problem and test the solution.  Will post the updated script to the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I figured this out with the help of @kenjikato.

@user3439894 pointed out my variable typing issues. Kenji's fixes resolved that issue and his reporting additions helped me troubleshoot more quickly and productively when the script still failed to move past the first entry in the list array.

With the help of our friend Google, one of the thrown errors lead me to [this document](https://applescriptlibrary.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/technical-note-tn2065-do-shell-script-in-applescript.pdf) which identified the fact that applescript and bash find don't always play nicely together, particularly when re-triggering the command through a repeat loop.

After a few failed attempts at fixing that loop, I wondered if the variable typing issues had been causing another approach I'd tried, which was using the repeat loop to build a single -iname string which contained all of the file types to be found.

So, I pulled the bash command and **do shell script** out of the loop and then injected my loop built file request string into it.

**Problem solved!**

Once I had it working, I organized and commented my code better, including renaming all the variables to make it more generic (not just QuickBook files) and to make the variables more descriptive of what they were capturing for use.

Updated code below.  Feel free to use it!

Thanks for all of the help!

```
#################################################
#   Search & Rescue Files on External Drives
#################################################
#   By Doug Daulton with Kenji Kato
#################################################
#   This script is called by an Automator
#   folder check on /Volumes
#
#   When a new volume is mounted the script:
#
#   1.  Creates a new folder on a target folder 
#       in the users home folder.
#
#   2.  Searches source drive for defined files
#       and copies them to the target folder.
#       
#       To configure, define these variables:
#           snrFileTypes
#           targetMasterFolder
#################################################

on adding folder items to thisFolder after receiving addedItems

    ###################################
    # Set Variables
    ###################################

    # Source Drive
    ###################################
    set sourceDriveName to item 1 of addedItems
    set sourcePath to POSIX path of sourceDriveName

    # File Types to Be "Rescued"
    ###################################
    set snrFileTypes to {"*qbb*", "*qbo*"}

    # Target Folder
    ###################################
    set targetMasterFolder to "00_QBB:"
    set targetMasterFolderPath to ((path to home folder as text) & targetMasterFolder)

    # Check that path has been set
    if not pathExists(targetMasterFolderPath) then
        display dialog "Master Target Folder does not exist. Files will not be copied."
        return
    end if

    # Create Target Folder
    ###################################
    set targetPath to targetMasterFolderPath & sourceDriveName
    set targetPath to POSIX path of targetPath
    set makeTargetFolder to "mkdir -p " & targetPath
    do shell script (makeTargetFolder)

    ###################################
    # Run The Search & Rescue
    ###################################
    try

        # Build snrFileTypesRequest
        ###################################

        # Initialize snrFileTypesRequest
        set snrFileTypeCurrent to (item 1 of snrFileTypes)
        set snrFileTypesRequest to "-iname \"" & snrFileTypeCurrent & "\""

        # Append snrFileTypesRequest until complete
        repeat with n from 2 to (count of snrFileTypes)
            set snrFileTypesCount to (count of snrFileTypes)
            set snrFileTypeCurrent to (item n of snrFileTypes)

            # Loop through snrFiletypes & append
            if (snrFileTypesCount > 1) then
                set snrFileTypesRequest to snrFileTypesRequest & " -o -iname \"" & snrFileTypeCurrent & "\""
            end if
        end repeat

        # Find & Copy Desired Files
        ###################################

        # inject snrFileTypesRequest into bash command
        set snrRescueOperation to "find " & sourcePath & " -type f \\( " & snrFileTypesRequest & " \\) -exec cp {} " & targetPath & " \\;"

        display dialog snrRescueOperation

        # execute the search & rescue (copy) via shell (Terminal) /bin/sh
        do shell script (snrRescueOperation)

        # Report Actionable Errors
        ###################################
        on error errStr number errorNumber
            display dialog "Could not copy files because " & errStr & " error# " & errorNumber
        return
    end try

end adding folder items to

#################################################
#   Path Check Subroutine
#################################################

on pathExists(targetMasterFolderPath) -- pathExists("path:to:folder: OR :file")
    try
        get targetMasterFolderPath as alias
        return true
    on error
        return false
    end try
end pathExists
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'll take my method of implementation and the 10 lines of `bash` _code_  which actually does more then the 39 (actual) lines of **AppleScript** _code_, over your method and _code_. The first 7 lines of my _code_ does what your 39 lines do.